# Need an idea for designing DB for a University -- Messeging system issue

Tags: database, database-design, authentication, erd

I have a University system project for my db lab.
I should have a unique login page for all the 3 user types: 1.student 2.Teacher 3.Supervisor

I already separated them in 3 tables(each has its unique properties).

My problems:

1. How to check when someone tries to log in?(which table should be checked and how to prevent duplicate usernames however they are in 3 different tables).
2. How to send messages between these 3 types although there is no central unique table to lookup(3 tables should be checked and there is a chance of username duplication)

My current ERD:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should have all the users with their type in one table and additional information in separate tables.

Comment: And how should I link it to these tables?answer:login(username,password) & Student(forgienkey:username,firstname,lastname,major) & ...

Comment: I would probably create a new primary auto number key for the login table and use that as a foreign key to the other tables

Answer (score 0):

you do not show any difference between the Students and the Professors in the schema.
also there is no 'supervisor' table.

i would suggest renaming the table to users - and adding a type or role column.

also:

the professors should be many to many with the courses also - assuming one professor can teach more than one course.

in the case where you combine the users, then there should also be a role on the association between users and courses identifying whether that user is a professor of that course, a student, an auditor, an associate, a substitute - etc.

Comment: yes, my ERD is not complete yet. If I merge all of them in one table, there would be no direct relation between an student and a course. I mean, there would be multiple relation types.

Comment: An example of an special attribute can be the "major".

Comment: In this example, we assumed that each course has only one Professor. Will it solve the problem you found with(course <--> professor)?